# Iterating through 2d array

Tags: java

Hi I want to iterate through every 12 `image` pixel.
If pixel is black i want to put 1 on my array else 0.

```
int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();

  
    int[][] pixels = new int[height / 12][width / 12];

    int counterX = 1;
    int counterY = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < width / 12; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height / 12; j++) {

            if (counterX == 1 && counterY == 1) {
                int rgb = image.getRGB(counterX, counterY);
                String s = Integer.toHexString(rgb);
                if (s.equals("ff000000")) {
                    pixels[i][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    pixels[i][j] = 0;
                }
                counterX += 12;

            } else {

                int rgb = image.getRGB(counterX, counterY);
                String s = Integer.toHexString(rgb);
                if (s.equals("ff000000")) {
                    pixels[i][j] = 1;
                } else {
                    pixels[i][j] = 0;
                }
                counterX += 12;


                if (counterX > width) {
                    counterX = 1;
                    counterY += 12;
                    if (counterY > height) {
                        counterY = height;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return pixels;
```

I have  Index 41 out of bounds for length 41 it is  happening in this line `pixels[i][j] = 0;`
Something's wrong with X.

Comment: Should `counterX` and `counterY` start at 1? I suggest you print the values of `counterX` and `counterY` and see if they are within the limits of `getRGB()` They may be exceeding the image size. Putting print statements at other key spots may also help and is usually the first debugging technique employed in cases like this.

Comment: You might also show the actual exception and the code around that linenumber.

Comment: ```   for (int h = 0; h < pixels.length; h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < pixels[h].length; w++) {
```
would be the way i'd iterate with the variable names being meaningful. Ugh, can you only do inline code in comments??